# Shipping charge based on weight

Tags: python, beginner

The program here is simply supposed to tell you the shipping charge based off of the weight of the package. I am just wondering if there is any further way to concise it? At the moment, I do not think it can go any further than that. The only place where I'm unsure whether I could improve it, could be Booleans. Possibly use a `while` statement?

```
def main():

    weight = eval(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))

    rate = 0

    if weight <= 2:
        rate += 1.25
    elif weight > 2 and weight <= 5:
        rate += 2.35
    elif weight > 5 and weight <= 10:
        rate += 4.05
    elif weight > 10:
        rate += 5.55

    charge = rate * weight

    print("The shipping charge is: $%s" % charge)

print(main())
```

Comment: `weight = eval(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))` it's extremely important to *not* do this. You do not want to evaluate untrusted code, it creates a massive security hole in your code.

Comment: @shuttle87 This would count as an answer in my opinion, even if small it is still really important and relevant to know! Next time consider making an answer instead of a comment. (relevant discussion http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none-lets-work-together-to-offer-ultimately-bet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some more thoughts, although some of it has been mentioned before:

- *Calculating shipping charge sounds like a function* – This sounds like something you could do multiple times, and as such should be made into a function
- *Trust in the `if` / `elif` ...* – It is unneccessary to do both the `if weight <= 2` and the `elif weight > 2`.
- *... or alternatively use a dictionary/list and a loop* – When you build repeating structures as the multiple `if` & `elif` you should consider if you can make this into a loop structure, which in general looks nicer than the repeated structure.
- *Seperate business logic from presentation logic* – In your case remove the `print()` arount the calling to main, and simplify `main()` to handle input/ouput, and let the function do the logic
- *Add the tagging to allow use as a module* – If you add the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block/tagging, you could reuse your module from another place when you want to calculate shipping charges
- *Use `int(input(..))` for integer input, `float(input(...))` or just `input(...)` for string* – These allows for better handling of your input. Also note that if you are using Python 2, you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.
- *Change to the newer `string.format`* – In Python 3 it is preferred to stop using the `%` operator, and rather use the [string formatting](//docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting). I.e. doing stuff like: `"The shipping charge is: ${:.2f}".format(charge)` which format the shipping charge as a float with 2 decimals.
- *Document your code using docstrings/comments* – Always nice to document constants or functions in your code!
- *Include error handling* – No point in calculating shipping charges of negative weiths for example. So a little input validation is always good

### Code refactoring

```
# WEIGHT_RATES is a list of tuples = (min_weight, rate),
# As it is reverse sorted, look from start to find the first
# entry where your weight is higher than min_weight, and use
# corresponding rate
WEIGHT_RATES = [
      ( 10, 5.55),
      (  5, 4.05),
      (  2, 2.35),
      (  0, 1.25)
    ]

def shipping_charge(weight):
    """Return shipping charge based upon the weight."""

    if weight < 0:
       raise ValueError("Can't calculate shipping charge of negative weights")

    for min_weight, rate in WEIGHT_RATES:
        if weight > min_weight:
            return weight * rate


def main():
    """Read a single weight, and calculate shipping charge"""

    weight = int(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))
    print('The shipping charge is: ${:,.2f}'.format(shipping_charge(weight)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Added: `shipping_charge_no_list`

As commented upon, your teacher is not fond of lists, so here is a version of the function without the list. Note that, in my opinion, it is a little better to change the order around, mainly because I'll expect the first case to be most prominent and should break out of the `if`-block firstly. But that is a matter of taste, and your mileage may vary.

```
def shipping_charge_no_list(weight):
    """Return shipping charge based upon the weight."""

    if weight < 0:
       raise ValueError("Can't calculate shipping charge of negative weights")

    if weight > 10:
        rate = 5.55
    elif weight > 5:
        rate = 4.05
    elif weight > 2:
        rate = 2.35:
    else
        rate = 1.25

    return weight * rate
```

Comment: thank you for such exhaustive explanation! It is much appreciated. This is for my Python Lab at school and my professor unfortunately wants things the specific way. I am already aware of loops and lists thanks to Codecademy (which is what I would use in the first place), but I would get marked down for that.

Comment: Also, I am confused about the list. Why are you using parentheses? To me it looks kind of like a dictionary, where there's a key and a value. If I were to do it similar to yours, I would do two lists and `zip` them together. I didn't know that by using parentheses, you create tuples **within** a single list.

Comment: @Paul, I use the list to avoid initialising an OrderedDict. An ordinary dict will _not_ maintain the order of the weights. And using `zip()` on two list, when you can write that the exact same thing using parentheses seems like extraneous work... Don't you agree?

Comment: I agree; I was just very surprised that I've never stumbled upon using dictionaries that way before. This makes the entire script look so much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: @Paul, `RATES` is _not_ a dictionary, it is a list of tuples. But it is a quite useful construct, and can easily be extend to multiple values of the tuple. It does however have downsides like easily find any given entry... If that is needed, one should seriously consider using an ordered dict.

Answer (score 11):

You are checking much more than you need to. Consider the first two cases:

```
if weight <= 2:
    # A
elif weight > 2 and weight <= 5:
    # B
```

If `weight <= 2`, we fall into case A. If we're not in case A, only then do we continue onto the next condition checks (because we're using `elif` and not `if`). As such, if we're even in the path that checks the condition which leads to `B`, we already know that `weight > 2`. Thus, that check is redundant and can be reduced to simply `weight <= 5`.

The whole body can become:

```
if weight <= 2:
    rate += 1.25
elif weight <= 5:
    rate += 2.35
elif weight <= 10:
    rate += 4.05
else:
    rate += 5.55
```

Which isn't just less code, it's easier to reason about since all your bounds are visually in the same column.

Answer (score 10):

As others have commented on the logic, I'll comment on the rest :)

```
weight = eval(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))
```

Why have you used `eval()`? It is used for running raw code from the input which you don't really need.

Instead, do:

```
int(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))
```

Here, you convert the input to an integer, at the same time. If you want to use floats, simply do:

```
float(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))
```

---

As far as I can see, there's no need to add to the rate because you're only calling the function once. So rate will **always** be 0 at the beginning.

So instead, remove the `rate = 0` and change the `rate += 1.25`, etc... to `rate = 1.25`, etc...

---

There's also no need to `print()` `main()` because you have a print statement already in it.

Instead, you could **return** the string that you are currently printing, or just remove the surrounding `print()` from `print(main())`

---

With those changes in mind:

```
def main():

    weight = int(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))

    if weight <= 2:
        rate = 1.25
    elif weight > 2 and weight <= 5:
        rate = 2.35
    elif weight > 5 and weight <= 10:
        rate = 4.05
    elif weight > 10:
        rate = 5.55

    charge = rate * weight

   return "The shipping charge is: $%s" % charge

print(main())
```

Comment: It's just how I've been taught and have always been confused. I assumed that as long as I'm using integers, that `eval( )` was necessary.

Comment: @Paul no, if you're inputting integers, convert the `input()` to an int via `int()` :) And for strings, just do a normal `input()` :)

Comment: Also, I just noticed that if I do use `int()`, I cannot use a float because it spits out a Value Error. Thank you, though! :)

Comment: @Paul If you want to use floats and not ingegers, convert to a float instead with `float()`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have covered all possible cases, the last

```
elif weight > 10:
    rate += 5.55
```

can just be:

```
else:
    rate += 5.55
```

Also, in python, you can do:

```
elif 2 < weight <= 5:
```

Finally, your main doesn't return anything, so instead of

```
print(main())
```

you can just do:

```
main()
```

Comment: Thank you! @fredtantini I didn't think it was possible dropping a variable between the two signs. I'm glad you mentioned.

Comment: @Paul This is called [interval comparion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436150/how-does-interval-comparison-work) and is pretty much unique to Python. Most (sane) languages would interpret this as `(2 < weight) <= 5`, which is nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

By extracting the computation of the rate to a different function, you can simplify the code by returning early when you know the rate:

```
def compute_rate(weight):
    if weight <= 2:
        return 1.25
    if weight <= 5:
        return 2.35
    if weight <= 10:
        return 4.05
    return 5.55
```

Used like this in main:

```
charge = compute_rate(weight) * weight
```

Comment: The original if .. elif chain short circuits evaluation in the same way. Please focus on the value of extracting the discrete logic to a separate method.

Comment: I think what @psaxton is saying is he's downvoting you.

Comment: @user1717828 he didn't downvote - there are no downvotes on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I like to separate logic from data, to make both more readable. Here, the key rate change points are in a separate dictionary. We can find the correct rate by checking from the end of the list. Shipping is calculated in the function, or we could return just the rate.

```
RATES = {
    0: 1.25,
    2: 2.35,
    5: 4.05,
    10: 5.55,
}

def calc_shipping(weight):
    # Make reversed key weight list
    key_weights = sorted(RATES.keys(), reverse=True)

    for more_than in key_weights:
        if weight > more_than:
            return RATES[more_than] * weight
    else:
        return 0.0
```

To test for the correctness of the solution compared to the original, I used this py.test parameterized function:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("weight, expected_shipping", [
    (0, 0),
    (1.5, 1.875),
    (2, 2.5),
    (2.0001, 4.700235),
    (4, 9.4),
    (5, 11.75),
    (5.0001, 20.250405),
    (8, 32.4),
    (10, 40.5),
    (15, 83.25),
])
def test_calc_shipping(weight, expected_shipping):
    # Check for approximate equality
    assert abs(calc_shipping(weight) - expected_shipping) < 0.0000001
```